# I only hear quzz when making a phone call using SIM800L module

Tags: gsm, sim

I made a board to make a phone call using SIM800L module. A PIC16F886 does the main roles, a PIC12F683 plays an audio message from a 24C256 EEPROM using PWM and sends it to SIM800L. The audio message is clear when I connect PIC12F683 PWM output to a speaker. The audio message is not clear but can be understood after making a phone call on a breadboard. But when I made the PCB I can hear only quzzzzzzzzzzzzzz on the other side after SIM800L make the call. What's the problem and ow can I solve it?
I attached the photo of my PCB, and the circuit diagram.
[image: circuit diagram]
[image: pcb]
[image: pcb that I made]
I also had a problem adjusting sound level before that is related to this project and is solved [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253447/pwm-signal-to-sim800-mic-noise-reduction).

Comment: I think the way you connected R17 is somewhat odd. Shouldn't it connect to ground?

Comment: @peter, I connected MICN to GND too on the breadboard, but the sound in this way (have R17 instead of ground connection) was better.

Answer (score 2):

The microphone input on the SIM800 is ment to interface an electret microphone. The input sees a *difference* between the voltages on MICP and MICN as its signal.

But the way it is connected now (R17 between MICN and C6) there will *never* be a voltage difference between MICN and MICP (other than the BIAS voltage ment to feed the microphone).

I guess the quzzz sound you hear are minute fluctuations in the current that the BIAS generator drives through R17. As there is no other input signal the module turns up the audio amplification and the quzzz gets audible.

To solve it: Disconnect R17 from C6, and connect it to ground. 
Now MICN will be static, MICP will 'move' with respect to it and the module will see input.

This modification creates a DC connection from MICN to ground. The datasheet is blank on what could happen if you do that. I guess with R17 it's ok, but it might make the BIAS generator and/or input stages unhappy. If the sound is not perfect yet, try adding a capacitor (say 100n) in series with R17.

It could still be that the PWM output is too loud for the mic input, and the sounds get distorted that way. In that case increase R5 to attenuate the PWM output further.

Comment: Good luck. I hope you'll add an answer with the new schematic when it works.

Comment: It does not worked.

Answer (score 1):

I reduced my microphone noise problem doing these two things:

1. Getting rid of small soldered helix antenna and instead using PCB antenna connected to u.Fl connector. Also, my PCB antenna is in approx. 5 cm distance from the board, so not right next to all the components.
2. Setting microphone gain to 0 with AT+CMIC.